# PHP echo select menu value but delete duplicate

Tags: php, jquery

I'm working on a profile update page and i have a form field where users can select enabled or disabled. When i echo the value, it has a duplicate and can be confusing for the user. How can i get rid of the duplicate?

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Change Status</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control btn-danger" id="status" name="status">
         <option value="<?php echo $status ?>"><?php echo $status ?></option>
         <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
         <option value="Enabled">Enabled</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, if the status is enabled and i hit the select menu its gonna say Enabled twice, same thing for disabled.

The only thing i thought of was to have another field labeled current status and have the select menu to change status.

I really dont want to do that.

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="currentstatus" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Current Status</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="currentstatus" name="currentstatus" value="<?php echo $status ?>">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Change Status</label>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select class="form-control btn-danger" id="status" name="status">
         <option value="<?php echo $status ?>"><?php echo $status ?></option>
         <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
         <option value="Enabled">Enabled</option>
      </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

This worked for me:

```
<option <?php if ($status=="Disabled") echo " selected"; ?>>Disabled</option>
<option <?php if ($status=="Enabled") echo " selected"; ?>>Enabled</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of outputting the selected value as *another option*, output it as the `selected` attribute of an existing option.  Something like this:

```
<select class="form-control btn-danger" id="status" name="status">
    <option value="Disabled" <?php echo ($status == "Disabled") ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Disabled</option>
    <option value="Enabled" <?php echo ($status == "Enabled") ? "selected" : ""; ?>>Enabled</option>
</select>
```

There are likely a variety of ways to achieve the same end result, but the point is to not *add* options based on the data you have but instead use that data to determine which of the existing, finite, hard-coded options you already have should be selected.

Comment: @JD6969: Ah, I forgot to close the parentheses.  Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Here is some jQuery that will let you change the value of the select box.

```js
function setStatusSelect(val) {
  $("select#status").val(val);
}

setStatusSelect('Enabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="status" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Change Status</label>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <select class="form-control btn-danger" id="status" name="status">
         <option value="Disabled">Disabled</option>
         <option value="Enabled">Enabled</option>
      </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you include the Jquery function at the top of the page (so that it loads quickly) then you can do something like this:

```
<?php

print("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
print("setStatusSelect(".$status.")");
print("</script>");

?>
```

to set the value.

I haven't tested the PHP portion, but I know the `jQuery` portion works.